# Strange behavior with post and pre increment operators in C

Tags: c, operators, undefined-behavior, pre-increment, sequence-points

When I do this -

```
int i = 4;
printf("\n %d", ++i + ++i);
```

I get 12 as the answer. But when I do this -

```
int i = 4;
int a,b,s;
a = ++i;
b= ++i;
s = a+b;
printf("%d", s);
```

I get 11 as the answer. Why?

I have tried both the code.

The expected value is 11 but why it is getting 12 in the first code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior). Turn on warnings and you'll see "warning: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'i'
      [-Wunsequenced]".

Comment: The second code fragment has well-defined behavior and gets the correct answer.  The first fragment has undefined behavior, ecause it tries to modify `i` twice between sequence points.  Always use code like the second fragment.

Comment: @ggorlen Unfortunately he's unlikely to see that warning, as compilers that can emit it are still rather rare.

Comment: @SteveSummit Ah, good to know. I used repl.it to get this running clang version 7.0.0-3~ubuntu0.18.04.1.

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet

```
int i = 4;
printf("\n %d", ++i + ++i);
```

has undefined behavior because there is no sequence point between calculations of expressions `++i`.

This code snippet

```
int i = 4;
int a,b,s;
a = ++i;
b= ++i;
s = a+b;
printf("%d", s);
```

is well-formed. The variable `a` gets the value of `i` after increment. So its value becomes equal to `5`.  At the same time `i` is also equal to `5`.

After this statement

```
b= ++i;
```

`b` and `i` are equal to `6`. So the sum of `a` and `b` is equal to `11`.